Manhwa about a saintess with disciples that had to physically obey her every command
A year ago, I read a manhwa but can't remember the name.
It was about a saintess, except no one knew she was the saintess as there was a fake saintess. I remember that the saintess had disciples that had to physically obey her every command. I think they were referred to as stars, maybe? I also think the lead had light blue hair.

It's manga, not manwha, but Because I, the True Saint, Was Banished, That Country Is Done For! does have blue hair.
